Couldn't update node.js on WSL
copying : node/20.12.2
   installed : v20.12.2 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v16.14.2 at /root/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.2/bin/node

I couldn't use node v20.12.2 in wsl vs code, but I could use it at my normal vs code
If I tried to activate node 20.12.2, the yarn became error
root@:/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc# yarn -v
ERROR: There are no scenarios; must have at least one.
root@:/hh-fcc/hardhat-simple-storage-fcc# yarn hardhat compile
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hardhat'


It seems you also have the (entirely different, older) [yarn program from the cmdtest package] installed (https://web.archive.org/web/20170310215903/http://git.liw.fi/cgi-bin/cgit/cgit.cgi/cmdtest/tree/README.yarn). It's for testing Unix command-line tools, it has nothing to do with node. If you don't use cmdtest, you can just uninstall it with sudo apt remove yarn (or if this doesn't work, sudo apt remove cmdtest).
Then run hash -r to update the command path cache.
Then, after switching to node 20, enable yarn for your new node version in your project again, according to the official instructions, using corepack enable.
See also this issue on GitHub asking for nvm to persist the corepack state across node versions, it explains that corepack itself doesn't support that. That's why you have to enable it again after switching versions once.

Try these steps,
nvm use 20.12.2


yarn add hardhat

Verify Node.js and Yarn Versions:
node -v
yarn -v

